# OneDrive REST API Post call Bad Request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I'm trying to use REST API in my app but I can't get it work.

I got authorization code successfully and saved it. (with `wl.offline_access` permission)

I want to sign in to OneDrive and upload files in background task, so I need refresh token. Then I make a POST call to get refresh token but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
var data = "client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf&client_secret=CLIENT_SCRET&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&grant_type=authorization_code";
data = Uri.EscapeDataString(data);

var webClient = new WebClient
{
    Headers =
    {
        [HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
};

webClient.UploadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    // e.Result throws an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'
    // e.Error = {"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."}
    // e.Error.Response.StatusCode = BadRequest
    // e.Error.Response.Headers = {Cache-Control: no-store
    //                             Pragma: no-cache
    //                             Content-Length: 113
    //                             Content-Type: application/json
    //                             Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    //                             X-WLID-Error: 0x80049D58
    //                             X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    //                             Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2015 20:22:04 GMT
    //                             Connection: close}
};

var uri = new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf",UriKind.Absolute);
webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", data);
```

Comment: *Then I make a POST call to get refresh token but it doesn't work.* Proof?

Answer (score 0):

The code retrieved during the code flow isn't valid for an extended period of time. What you'll want to do is store the refresh token returned by the POST call above immediately after retrieving the code. Then you can use that refresh token to retrieve an access token offline. Refresh tokens are valid for one year and you will receive a new one whenever you retrieve a new access token. The OneDrive [code flow documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#code-flow) has more information.